# Port forwarding secure mail ports to the server secure ports?

Tags: centos, certificates, imap

I have a shared server setup with several users. I'm in the process of securing their E-Mail ports. I have a certificate for the server. And when connecting via `servername`:993/995/465 it shows the certificate. Everything is fine.

What the users are used on doing, is add `mail.domainname.tld` to their mail clients. What I want to happen is that when users connect with the mail client to

- `imap.domainname.tld:993` it gets forwarded to `shared.server:993`
- `imap.domainname.tld:995` it gets forwarded to `shared.server:995`
- `smtp.domainname.tld:465` it gets forwarded to `shared.server:465`

shared.server:993 has a certificate. I want them to be able to keep using mail.domainname without getting a certificate mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the better option would be to register a multi-domain certificate tied to the server. This will then allow all the domains to connect securely with a valid certificate as long as it's to the right IP. Still secure just allows the domains.